# Playwright on Github screenshots on failure not working

Tags: javascript, github-actions, playwright

My playwright.config.ts includes:

```
use: {
  ...
  screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
}
```

and test failures result in screenshots being saved in /test-results when they fail locally. But when the tests fail when run in Github Actions, no screenshots are taken. So it's impossible for me to tell what's going wrong in my tests, which pass fine locally.

The only CI-specific parts of my config are:

```
/* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
/* Retry on CI only */
retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
/* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
reporter: process.env.CI ? 'github' : 'list',
```

ETA: my action.yml attempts to upload the /test-results folder but it's always completely empty, as no screenshots were taken:

```
- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  if: always()
  with:
    name: playwright-test-results
    path: test-results/
```

Comment: found any solution yet?
i have the same problem that playwright logs that the screenshot was created but github logs that no artifact was uploaded because the folder is empty.

Answer (score 0):

We can upload the test-results folder as a run artifact using GitHub's "upload-artifact" action post suite execution.

Alternatively, a step can be added in the workflow after the test run to upload the images to the desired location.

Comment: I am already uploading it but the test-results folder is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
// playwright.config.ts
import { PlaywrightTestConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
    forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
    retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 1,
    use: {
        trace: 'on',
        screenshot: 'only-on-failure', // Capture screenshot after each test failure.
        video: 'retain-on-failure', //Record video only when retrying a test for the first time.
        headless: true,
        viewport: { width: 1280, height: 720 },
        baseURL: "https:xxxxx",
        launchOptions: {
            slowMo: 50,
            logger: {
                isEnabled: (name, severity) => name === 'browser',
                log: (name, severity, message, args) => console.log(`${name} ${message}`)
            }
        },
        actionTimeout: 10 * 1000,
        navigationTimeout: 30 * 1000
    },
    expect: {
        timeout: 10 * 1000
    },
    timeout: 90000,
    outputDir: `${__dirname}/build`,
    projects: [
        {
            name: 'chromium',
            use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] }
        }
    ],
    reporter: [
        ['junit', { outputFile: 'build/results.xml' }],
        ['html', { outputFolder: 'build/html-report', open: 'never' }],
        ['list']
    ]
};
export default config;
```

```
// .gitlab-ci.yml

.e2e:
  stage: postdeploy
  image: xxxxx
  script:
    - pnpm xxx
    - pnpm nx test e2e // "test": "playwright test --output build --workers 2",
  after_script:
    - ls -l tests/e2e
    - cp -r tests/e2e/build ./results

  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: never
    name: 'test-artifacts'
    paths:
      - results/html-report
    exclude:
      - results/results.xml
    reports:
      junit: results/results.xml
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your uploads folder is empty, you're probably attempting to use a relative path.  `upload-artifact` doesn't respect the `working-directory` setting: https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/232#issuecomment-964235360

Once that's fixed, you can download the zip & screenshots will be inside